# Escaping special characters in SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I need your help on this: I am using SQL Server 2008 and have a stored procedure which is used to retrieve values from a table column.

Column of table contains description which could have anything including all special characters.

Is there any way I can escape all special characters ?

Thanks

Comment: Can you please explain more? and why do you want to escape the special characters? special characters as data not objects' names are special only in certain cases not all the time, like in the `LIKE` predicate for example.

Comment: Hi, i have frontend application where i have got search screen. search screen contains different search parameters including description which is a text box and user could enter anything in it so i want to escape any special character because that special character could be a part of string which user is inputting into text box

Comment: Please edit your question and explain that in it and how this user supposed to search for that description, so that other user see that and can help you as well. So the user search with the `LIKE` operator and you want to make the user able for searching for `%` and other special character?

Answer (score 2):

try this

> WHERE Description LIKE '%\ any text%'

here \ means ESCAPE